# Dropdown nav menu not showing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown, nav

So first I would like to say I am extremely new to coding so please keep that in mind!

I was trying to create a dropdown nav bar and I'm having all sorts of issues. First, between the dropdown menu items there is white spaces which I don't understand at all. Second, the actual dropdown portion is not showing up at all when mousing over. I've been trying to fix this for an incredibly long time and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

The website with the issue is: (Dropdown is all the way at the bottom of the page)
https://ist2w.purdueglobal.edu/2204A/IT214-01/MeganAllen5/navigation.html

Here is the html code:

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn20e.png)

And the css:

```
#drop_nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

}



#drop_nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margins: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}



#drop_nav li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
    align-items: center;

}



#drop_nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 64px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-weight: 500;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: width .4s, height .4s;
}



#drop_nav a:hover {
    width: 80px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #dc143c;
}




#drop_nav li:hover .submenu > li {
display: block;
top: 0px;
}



.submenu {

}



.submenu li:hover {
display: block;
top: 0px;
}

#drop_nav li:hover .submenu > li {
display: block;
top: 0px;
}

.submenu li {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}

.submenu {
display: flex;
flex-direction: vertical;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.submenu li {
position: absolute;
}

.submenu li:hover {
display: flex;
}


.arrow {
    margin-left: 8px;
    color: #a9a9a9
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

PLEASE HELP!!!!!
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/vYjvxyq).

In this example I only illustrate how the hovering and opening of the menus works. I didn't use any other styling. Note that the `<li>.....</li>` encapsulates the menus completely.

This is all the styling that is needed to open and close the menus:

```
#drop_nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

#drop_nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: initial;
}
```